# Use of literals in hygienic macros in Scheme

Tags: macros, scheme, r5rs

In the Scheme language (let's take R5RS as a language reference) hygienic macros can be defined amongst others with the construct `(define-syntax <keyword> <transformer>)` where `<keyword>` is the name of the macro and `<transformer>` describes the `<pattern>` the macro will match and a `<template>` describes how that pattern should be transformed. The `<transformer>` has the following form: `(syntax-rules <literals> <syntax-rule> ...)` and each `<syntax-rule>` is of the form `(<pattern> <template>)`.

For example:

```
(define-syntax swap
  (syntax-rules ()
      (; pattern to be matched:
       (swap x y)
       ; template the pattern will get replaced by:
       (let ((tmp x))
         (set! x y)
         (set! y tmp)))))
```

However, it is also allowed to specify some `<literals>` as part of the `syntax-rules` declaration.  I understand from the language specification that any identifier that appears in the `<pattern>` of a `<syntax-rule>` is a pattern variable, unless it is the `<keyword>` that begins the pattern, or is listed in `<literals>`, or is the identifier `...`. Pattern variables match arbitrary input elements and are used to refer back in the template to elements of the input matched in the pattern. Identifiers that appear in `<literals>` however are interpreted as literal identifiers to be matched against corresponding subforms of the input.

In practice, in almost all of the examples that one can find this list of literals `()` is kept empty (as in the example above).

*Can someone provide me with a simple example that illustrates the relevance of having such literals. In what realistic use-case would it make sense to have such literals? A concrete and simple example would be helpful.*

Comment: `else` in a `cond` is one example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create "within-fix" expression syntaxes.
Silly example:

```
(define-syntax swap
  (syntax-rules (with unless)
       (swap x with y unless c)
       (when (not c)
         (let ((tmp x))
           (set! x y)
           (set! y tmp))))))
```

Test:

```
> (define a 1)
> (define b 2)
> (swap a with b unless (< a b))
> a
1
> b
2
> (swap a with b unless (< b a))
> a
2
> b
1
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that was indeed a simplistic, but clear answer. Thanks. There was just a missing bracket somewhere in your answer. Here's the correct version:

```
(define-syntax swap
  (syntax-rules (with unless)
       ((swap x with y unless c)
        (if (not c)
         (let ((tmp x))
           (set! x y)
           (set! y tmp))))))
```

Comment: This is a dangerous example as `with` is usually not bound, and the matching of unbound literal identifiers is fragile.  As a general rule, it is best to bind all identifiers that are literally matched.

Comment: @Marc In this case why would it be a problem if `with` is unbound given that it is just meant as a keyword here? (It would be more problematic if `with` was bound but even then it would work since the `with` variable is not used in the expansion part of the macro anyway. (I am trying to understand here what the best pratices are of using the literals list or not, and how to make sure that such literals are bound or not. Or is it better to avoid the use of literals in `syntax-rules` which would explain that only very few examples that I found seem to use it.)

Comment: @KimMens In the standard macros of R6RS and R7RS that use keywords, the keywords are bound.  This is a point for consistency.  Now if a keyword is not bound in the lexical environment of the macro, it must also be unbound in the lexical environment of the macro use.  However, this may not always be achievable because of some outer binding.  Now, on cannot locally unbind a keyword, but one can always import a bound keyword and bound keywords can be renamed (in the import clause) because bound keywords are matched by binding, not name.

Comment: @KimMens You may be interested in this tutorial if you want to learn more about Scheme macros: https://mnieper.github.io/scheme-macros/README.html

Answer (score 2):

The literals list is to get symbols to be treated the same way as strings. Eg.  in this example only the string "hello" as the first argument will match the rule:

```
(define-syntax example
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(test "hello" ...) (...)]))
```

However if we switch this to match a symbol:

```
(define-syntax example
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(test hello ...) (...)]))
```

Then this will actually match the same as the previous string example since a symbol matches ANY data token and binds it. If we want it only to match the symbol `hello` we add it to the literals list:

```
(define-syntax example
  (syntax-rules (hello)
    [(test hello ...) (...)]))
```

You can use `hello` in the expansion and in the case `hello` is a bound variable it will be the same variable that just happens to be named `hello`. Because of this we can break hygiene in syntax-rules as demonstrated by [Oleg's paper (PDF)](https://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/Dirty-Macros.pdf).

Comment: So you mean to say that you can use `hello` in the expansion but in the case hello is an already bound variable in the global scope outside, we break the hygiene inside syntax-rules because the outside value will be used inside? Is there a way to enforce in the pattern that hello is actually a variable that is unbound?

Comment: @KimMens Not really. An example of hygiene breakage is anaphoric `if` where the test is cached in the variable `it` so that this works `(aif test (list it) #f)`. Now a naive implementation that expands it to `(let ((it test)) (if it (list it) #f)))` won't work since `(list it)` will point to an `it` in the global scope and not the one the macro created. If you look at the PDF you'll see that the trick is to use macro to traverse the consequent and search for`it` and use that when making `let`